# How to remove CiviCRM links from Drupal user account page?

Tags: drupal, user-account

By default CiviCRM adds links for `» View Contact Record` and `» View Contact Dashboard` on the Drupal user account page for users that have permission to do these things.

[image: civi links in drupal account]

These links have proven to be confusing to new users when they log in and see their user account page (we have a "dashboard" in our Drupal system and they get confused when this link leads them to their CiviCRM contact dashboard, which is not helpful to them).

I know that I can:

1. Use CSS to simply hide them
2. Use a preprocess function in template.php for my Drupal theme to unset these from the array of user account items

But both of these are theme-specific solutions.

Is there a CiviCRM way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Permissions are going to be your friend here. If it's a Drupal site you can set a variety of roles with permissions to access parts of CiviCRM; ie:

- CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard
- CiviCRM: access CiviCRM
- CiviCRM: view my contact
- CiviCRM: edit my contact

To supress the View Contact Record link, remove the edit and view my contact permissions from the relevant roles.

If you want to get more granular then you can do so within CiviCRM's ACL (Access Control) settings

Answer (score 3):

If this is on drupal 8, You can hide these links from -

- Configuration -> People -> Account settings `/admin/config/people/accounts`
- Choose `Manage Display` tab which navigates to `/admin/config/people/accounts/display`

[image]

`CiviCRM record link` and `dashboard link` is what you need make sure is disabled.

Comment: Just discovered that too!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the rules engine to redirect users to the page you want them to see post login or logout. 
We use rules to check to see if the person is a paid up member and if they are not we send them to the renew page - if they are paid up we send them to the members home page.

We have set up a webform where their profile page and username and password - if a user tries to login or select profile we send them to the webform to modify profile or drupal info.

hoped that helped